# layout of elemets in JFrame - java swing

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a problem with dispositions of elements in frame.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiQEy.jpg)
First function is responsible for layout only first Panel with two JLabels and Button. I would like to have one JLabel and Button side by side and one JLabel below. In second step I created the method which will be add new JPanels in loop when I add new records to my Map (using TextField, ect)
but when I use it like below I don't see all my elemets. Problem begins when I add new JPanel in second method.

```
public void startFirstRecord() {
        // License Plate number + image
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(licname);
        JLabel name = new JLabel("Name: " + fullname);
        JButton details1 = new JButton("Details");
        panel1.add(label1);
        panel1.add(details1);
        panel1.add(name);
        f.add(panel1);
        label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users//tab.jpg"));
        label1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel1.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 100);


    }

    public void restRecords(){
        ArrayList<JPanel> label = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < vehiclelist.size(); i++) {
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
            JButton details2 = new JButton("Details");
            JLabel name2 = new JLabel("Name: " + fullname);
            label2 = new JLabel(licname);
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users//tab.jpg"));
            label2.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            label2.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            label2.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            panel2.add(label2);
            panel2.add(details2);
            panel2.add(name2);
            panel2.setBounds(10,(i*50)+60,500,100);
            label.add(panel2);
        }
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        for(JPanel j:label) {
            p.add(j);
           p.setBounds(10,10,500,100);
           p.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        }
        f.add(p);
        f.repaint();
    }
```

I would like something like that

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiQEy.jpg)

Comment: `p.setBounds(10,10,500,100);` is pointless, make use of appropriate layout managers. I'm also wondering if this could better achieved through the use of a `JTable` or `JList`. `p.setLayout(new GridLayout());` in the loop is resetting the layout information, basically throwing out everything that came before it

Comment: Show an image of how you want the layout to look like.

Comment: I added the image

Answer (score 1):

There's to much repetition in your code, this is screaming for a factory method.

`setBounds` is clear sign of issues, you shouldn't be using it and instead, should be making use of appropriate layout managers.

So I took you `startFirstRecord` method and re-wrote to use a `GridBagLayout` instead so it could so something more like...

[image]

```
    public void startFirstRecord() {
        // License Plate number + image
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Name");
        JLabel name = new JLabel("Name: blah");
        JButton details1 = new JButton("Details");

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        panel1.add(label1, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        panel1.add(details1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
        panel1.add(name, gbc);
        label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

        add(panel1);

    }
```

After looking over your `restRecords`, I ripped out the panel creation and created a factory method instead...

```
    protected JPanel makePanel(int index) {
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("licname " + index);
        JLabel name = new JLabel("Name: " + index);
        JButton details1 = new JButton("Details");

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        panel1.add(label1, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        panel1.add(details1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
        panel1.add(name, gbc);
        label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

        return panel1;
    }
```

which, oddly enough, is the pretty much the same code as your `startFirstRecord`.

Next I modified your `resetRecords` method to make use of a `GridBagLayout` as well...

[image]

```
public void restRecords() {
    ArrayList<JPanel> label = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        label.add(makePanel(i));
    }
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    for (JPanel j : label) {
        p.add(j, gbc);
    }

    add(p);
}
```

Now, if you would prefer to have the panels aligned to the top, you could simply add

```
gbc.weighty = 1;
p.add(new JPanel(), gbc);
```

after the second loop, which will add a "filler" component to the end which will want to take up the remaining vertical space (but add no height to the overall preferred size)

But wait, what if you have more rows then you have vertical space?  Then wrap the `p` (great name by the way) `JPanel` in a `JScrollPane`

See:

- [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

I think you would also benefit from having a look at:

- [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

The last two, however, will require you to think differently about how your users would interact with your data, but they are better suited towards the task you seem to be trying to implement.

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            //startFirstRecord();
            restRecords();
        }

        protected JPanel makePanel(int index) {
            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("licname " + index);
            JLabel name = new JLabel("Name: " + index);
            JButton details1 = new JButton("Details");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            panel1.add(label1, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel1.add(details1, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            panel1.add(name, gbc);
//            f.add(panel1);
//            label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users//tab.jpg"));
//            label1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
//            panel1.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 100);

            return panel1;
        }

        public void startFirstRecord() {
            // License Plate number + image
            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Name");
            JLabel name = new JLabel("Name: blah");
            JButton details1 = new JButton("Details");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            panel1.add(label1, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel1.add(details1, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            panel1.add(name, gbc);
//            f.add(panel1);
//            label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users//tab.jpg"));
//            label1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
//            panel1.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 100);

            add(panel1);

        }

        public void restRecords() {
            ArrayList<JPanel> label = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                label.add(makePanel(i));
            }
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            for (JPanel j : label) {
                p.add(j, gbc);
            }

            gbc.weighty = 1;
            p.add(new JPanel(), gbc);

            add(new JScrollPane(p));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I changed the first method the same of you and at the end only add  f.add(panel1,gbc); because f it's my frame I don't see anything in frame

Comment: shift-ctrl-c .. tend to break code formatting here (don't want to touch it myself here, might get it wrong without my IDE :)

Comment: @henry58 Did you `revalidate` and `repaint` the frame - I've add my fully runnable example - beyond that's it's all guess work

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi! Thank you! All is working! :) but only one details in method restRecord I see too short JLabels with elements.. It is a little bit cut.. I tryied use ex. gbc.gridheight = 3; but still nothing, could you help me ?